# phpMyAdmin Virtual MySQL Instance

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Currently I have phpMyAdmin and MySQL installed on my server. I now want to provide access to phpMyAdmin to a friend of mine so he can setup his own databases and users, however I don't want him to be able to see or modify my databases.

Is this possible to do with a simple privilege account or do I require some kind of MySQL virtualization? I know cPanel installations provide this feature for web hosts, but I don't need or can afford cPanel at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into MySQL Security [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-management-sql.html) specifically section 13.7.1.3 Grant statement. You could secure your DB from your friend logging in which will prevent him from seeing anything in that DB on PHPMyAdmin. Or you could create a DB for him to use and allow him access to that DB only.

You never mentioned if he will be on Localhost or will you need to open up MySQL for remote logins from other than Localhost which is the default behavior..

Comment: Spot on about permissions, but if the friend has web access to Svenskunganka's phpMyAdmin then no need to open up MySQL to the world. The friend doesn't need direct MySQL access, only to be able to access the phpMyAdmin installation. However, it's good to take measures to secure it (use a non-standard name, disable anonymous passwords, etc).